# Evaluate LaTeX syntax in a loop inside knitr chunk & adjust plot dpi

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Sorry if this question is very stupid. I am trying to run regressions and send summary tables and diagnostic plots to a PDF file. I found this package is very helpful, but have two basic questions.

1. Can I use LaTeX to format page inside a Chunk?
2. Is there a way to reduce the size of plots (I need to reduce pdf file size)? I tried to set dpi and use png rather than plot, which did not work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{Risk $\sim$ log(Parameters)}
<<fig.width=5,  fig.height=4.5, message=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, fig.align="center", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
library(R.matlab)
for (k in 1:6){
data_t=readMat("I:\\Dropbox\\Rregression\\matlab_size.mat")

data=data.frame(NA, nrow = length(data_t[[1]]), ncol = 7)
data=data.frame(rho=data_t[[1]],Risk=data_t[[2]],Mass.f=data_t[[3]],Mass.utf=data_t[[4]],Mass.w=data_t[[5]],
                ach=data_t[[6]],p=data_t[[7]])

data2=log(subset(data,select=-c(Risk)))
N_reg=dim(data2)[2]
num_ele=k
Comb=combn(N_reg,num_ele)
N_comb=ncol(Comb)
Results=data.frame(NA,ncol=4,nrow=N_comb)
TSS=sum((data$Risk-mean(data$Risk))^2)

for (i in 1:N_comb){  
  data_temp=data2[,Comb[,i]]  
  lm_temp=lm(data$Risk~as.matrix(data_temp))
  name=paste("lm_", i, sep="")
  assign(name, lm_temp)
  Results[i,1]=summary(lm_temp)$r.squared
  Results[i,2]=summary(lm_temp)$adj.r.squared
  Results[i,3]=sum(resid(lm_temp)^2)
  Results[i,4]=sum((fitted(lm_temp)-mean(fitted(lm_temp)))^2)
} 
colnames(Results)=c("R2", "Adj_R2", "RSS", "ESS")
best_col=which(Results[,2]==max(Results[,2]))

cat ('Number of independent variables=', k)
print (summary(eval(parse(text=(paste("lm_", best_col, sep=""))))))
print (Results[best_col,])
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(3,3,3,3))
plot(eval(parse(text=(paste("lm_", best_col, sep=""))))) #question 2: is there a way to reduce dpi of plot? 
\newpage #Here is question 1, I want to add a page break after printing a pair of summary table and plots
}

@
\end{document}
```

#### Update

Found a format issue when you involved a loop inside a chunk. Based on Yihui's suggestions, I ran

```
library(devtools)
install_github('evaluate', 'hadley')
install_github('knitr', 'yihui')
```

in R Console. However, met the following errors related to vignettes:

```
* installing the package to re-build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('knitr-intro.Rnw')"
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/Rscript -e \library(knitr); knit2pdf(knitr-intro.Rnw)\'
make: *** [knitr-intro.pdf] Error 1
Error in tools::buildVignettes(dir = ".") : running 'make' failed
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build "C:\Users\th\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSMRGAq\yihui-knitr-568a092" --no-manual --no-resave-data' had status 1
```

So, any suggestions on how to solve this? I have installed MikTex 2.9, and tried to download Knitr package directly from Git and build in Windows shell. I had the following errors:

```
C:\Users\th\Documents\R\win-library\2.15>R CMD build knitr --no-vignettes
* checking for file 'knitr/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'knitr':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
 ERROR
computing Rd index failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have simplified your example a lot. Answers to two questions (see http://yihui.name/knitr/options for detailed documentation):

1. yes, use `results='asis'`;
2. if you want to use the `png` device, you can set smaller `dpi` for the chunk; R's `pdf()` device already compresses plots, and `png` is probably the only choice if the default PDF compression is not satisfactory to you; the default `dpi` is 72, and I do not think smaller values will help a lot

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

hi

<<output-tex, results='asis'>>=
x = rnorm(1000)
cat('\\newpage')
@

here is a plot

<<smaller-png, dev='png', dpi=30>>=
plot(x)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am a little confused once I put the chunk inside a loop. The first page break is not placed properly. Do you have any ideas about it? Thanks! Here is the code         '\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<message=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, fig.align="center", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
for (i in 1:3){
cat (i)
x = rnorm(1000)
plot(x)
cat('\\newpage')
}
@
\end{document}'

Comment: @tao.hong That is a bug which has been reported for a few times (e.g. https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/issues/14) It has been fixed, and you need to `library(devtools); install_github('evaluate', 'hadley'); install_github('knitr', 'yihui')`

Comment: It seems like I am closer to the destination. However, I am some problems of installing knitr from github. Please check my updates for the details. Thanks!

Comment: I installed Rtools216.exe from your link, but still encountered the same error...

Comment: @tao.hong You typed `R CMD build knitr --no-vignettes` but does the directory `knitr` exist under `C:\Users\th\Documents\R\win-library\2.15` at all?? Why did you download the source package to `C:\Users\th\Documents\R\win-library\2.15`? I mean that is very unusual since that is usually the destination of R packages after installation; you could have downloaded to `C:\Users\th\Documents\` and install it from there.

Comment: It is working now! You are right, I need to compile the package outside R library and do a local installation. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: one more thing. Is it possible to include both cat('\\newpage'), and print(variable name) in the same chunk? Or have you tried to include two chunks in a loop? Thanks

Comment: @tao.hong Please ask different questions in different posts instead of sticking at this one forever.